# Reverse Ajax with JSF?

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, jsf-2

Is it possible to work with reverse Ajax in JSF 2.0?

I could work with Ajax in JSF, but I don't know how to keep rendering. Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With reverse Ajax you have polling where the client repeatedly queries the server looking for a response, and you have pushing where the server keeps a connection with the client and sends a response when available.

Richfaces has [`<a4j:poll>`](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/poll.jsf) and [`<a4j:push>`](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/push.jsf) as part of its ajax support.

> The `<a4j:push>` periodically perform
>   AJAX request to server, to simulate
>   'push' data.
>
> The main difference between `<a4j:push>`
>   and `<a4j:poll>` components is that
>   `<a4j:push>` makes request to minimal
>   code only (not to JSF tree) in order
>   to check the presence of messages in
>   the queue. If the message exists the
>   complete request will be performed.
>   The component doesn't poll registered
>   beans but registers EventListener
>   which receives messages about events.

Answer (score 1):

Primefaces has [p:poll](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/poll.jsf).

`<a4j:push>` has the advantage to use CDI events.