# How keep updating message with RichFaces 4?

Tags: jsp, jsf, jsf-2, richfaces, ajax4jsf

i'm new with RichFaces 4 and JSF 2, i'm working with both together.
How do i keep some message updating all time using RichFaces ?
E.g: a clock, where the server keep sending a message to the client.

Could someone provide some code where it show how do that ?

Thanks.

Best regards,
Valter Henrique.

Answer (score 2):

Reverse AJAX/comet would be the way. See this question for additional details: [Reverse Ajax with JSF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6365331/reverse-ajax-with-jsf)

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a4j:poll and render the clock component.